# How to drag and drop only particular selected node without affecting child nodes in gojs chart API

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am using GoJs chart plugin to make a heirarchy. Now in this I want to drag a node in heirarchy without changing the structure at all.
for Example, in the attached image if the node "Luke warm" is moved the only that node should be draggable not the child nodes i.e. "Meg meehen hoffa" and "Al ligori". The child node should stay at that position only as it is.

[Please see this image for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsF9P.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is in fact the default behavior.  However your code may have set **DraggingTool.dragsTree** to true.  If that is the case, don't set it, or set it to false.